# TFS Build not finding Dlls

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am new to TFS build. I am using TFS Visual Studio Template.
[image]

My app uses dev express dlls. 
All my devexpress dlls are checked into Common Folder:

[image]

When I run the build, build agent is failing with unable to find dev express component. Its looking for dlls under : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1

```
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z                  For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z                  Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core.winmd", but it didn't exist.
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z                  Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core.dll", but it didn't exist.
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z                  Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core.exe", but it didn't exist.
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0427439Z                  Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core.winmd", but it didn't exist.
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0427439Z                  Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core.dll", but it didn't exist.
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0427439Z                  Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core.exe", but it didn't exist.

2017-05-23T19:15:03.7771166Z      7>ResolveAssemblyReferences:
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z          Primary reference "DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core, Version=15.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a".
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core, Version=15.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z      7>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DevExpress.Charts.v15.2.Core, Version=15.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [E:\agent\CentralCompliance\_work\9\s\CentralCompliance\CentralCompliance.csproj]
2017-05-23T19:15:04.0271172Z                  For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}".
```

Any idea why its not looking into the common folder? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: How does your project reference these dlls? What do the `<HintPath>` values of `<Reference>` items of the project for these files contain?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git for source control?

Comment: I am using TFS as source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the VS designer specificity, all designer assemblies should be installed in the GAC. Guess this is why it's looking for  dlls under:
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1`  instead of your common folder.  It's not possible to deploy those assemblies to computers  without DevExpress installation. So does the build agent. The design assemblies which will be put into the GAC during the  DevExpress installation.

Besides to avoid the license issue, you should also need to install the DevExpress on build agent.

> We are verifying and integrating the license information at the
>   "building an application" stage. So, it's necessary to have our
>   components **installed and registered on a machine**. Otherwise, the
>   trial window may appear.  You can organize a build server and build
>   projects there. **The build server should have the components
>   installed as well**, however, you can be sure that you will not get a
>   licensing issue.

More details please take a look at below link：

- [Is it possible to keep DevExpress dlls in TFS](http://Is%20it%20possible%20to%20keep%20DevExpress%20dlls%20in%20TFS)
- [Add DevExpress libraries to TFS source control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T205251)

Comment: Patrick, thanks for detailed description. I installed devexpress on my build server and all good now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install DevExpress on your build agent. The build process restores the dependencies by using a local DevExpress installation.